# How to compile PHP with parameters on Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: php, apache, parameters, compilation, osx-lion

I simply want to do this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.installation.php, but I have no idea how to add these parameters to my local standard PHP5 installation on my Mac OS X Lion.

Can anyone please tell me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.glenscott.co.uk/blog/2011/08/29/install-mcrypt-php-extension-on-mac-os-x-lion/

Answer (score 1):

- http://www.coolestguyplanettech.com/how-to-install-mcrypt-for-php-on-mac-osx-lion-10-7-development-server/
- http://remonpel.nl/2012/01/adding-mcrypt-to-your-osx-lion-php-install/

Comment: Independent from mcrypt, how to add these paramters?

Comment: You will need to use the terminal to add these parameters.
This can give you some help about how do add these parameters using the OSX Terminal: http://techxplorer.com/2011/03/06/enabling-mcrypt-support-in-php-on-mac-os-x/